# Phone directories in Android and problems with getting anything from them

Tags: java, android, android-studio, directory

Hi Stackoverflow community!
At first I want to say that I am a rookie in programming. Recently I tried to get photos from my phone directories by my app. It seems pretty hard to do, because I have only succeded in displaying my Camera directory, but not for example Download or Screenshots. It is really strange that Android Studio cannot resolve DOWNLOAD word in the line `directories.add(filePaths.DOWNLOAD);`
What is wrong with my code??? Or with me and my lack of experience...
My code:

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "GalleryFragment";


    //constants
    private static final int NUM_GRID_COLUMNS = 3;


    //widgets
    private GridView gridView;
    private ImageView galleryImage;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private Spinner directorySpinner;

    //vars
    private ArrayList<String> directories;
    private String mAppend = "file:/";
    private String mSelectedImage;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
        galleryImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.galleryImageView);
        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        directorySpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerDirectory);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        directories = new ArrayList<>();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: started.");

        ImageView shareClose = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivCloseShare);
        shareClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: closing the gallery fragment.");
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        });


        TextView nextScreen = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvNext);
        nextScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: navigating to the final share screen.");

                if (isRootTask()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image), mSelectedImage);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AccountSettingsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image), mSelectedImage);
                    intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.return_to_fragment), getString(R.string.edit_profile_fragment));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    getActivity().finish();
                }

            }
        });

        init();

        return view;
    }

    private boolean isRootTask() {
        if (((ShareActivity) getActivity()).getTask() == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        FilePaths filePaths = new FilePaths();

        //check for other folders indide "/storage/emulated/0/pictures"
        if (FileSearch.getDirectoryPaths(filePaths.PICTURES) != null) {
            directories = FileSearch.getDirectoryPaths(filePaths.PICTURES);
        }
        directories.add(filePaths.CAMERA);
        directories.add(filePaths.DOWNLOAD);

        ArrayList<String> directoryNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < directories.size(); i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "init: directory: " + directories.get(i));
            int index = directories.get(i).lastIndexOf("/");
            String string = directories.get(i).substring(index);
            directoryNames.add(string);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, directoryNames);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        directorySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        directorySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: selected: " + directories.get(position));

                //setup our image grid for the directory chosen
                setupGridView(directories.get(position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }


    private void setupGridView(String selectedDirectory) {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupGridView: directory chosen: " + selectedDirectory);
        final ArrayList<String> imgURLs = FileSearch.getFilePaths(selectedDirectory);

        //set the grid column width
        int gridWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int imageWidth = gridWidth / NUM_GRID_COLUMNS;
        gridView.setColumnWidth(imageWidth);

        //use the grid adapter to adapter the images to gridview
        GridImageAdapter adapter = new GridImageAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_grid_imageview, mAppend, imgURLs);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //set the first image to be displayed when the activity fragment view is inflated
        try {
            setImage(imgURLs.get(0), galleryImage, mAppend);
            mSelectedImage = imgURLs.get(0);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "setupGridView: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: selected an image: " + imgURLs.get(position));

                setImage(imgURLs.get(position), galleryImage, mAppend);
                mSelectedImage = imgURLs.get(position);
            }
        });

    }


    private void setImage(String imgURL, ImageView image, String append) {
        Log.d(TAG, "setImage: setting image");

        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

        imageLoader.displayImage(append + imgURL, image, new ImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

FilePaths sorry for not formatting

```
public class FilePaths {

    //"storage/emulated/0"
    public String ROOT_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

    public String PICTURES = ROOT_DIR + "/Pictures";
    public String CAMERA = ROOT_DIR + "/DCIM/camera";

    public String FIREBASE_IMAGE_STORAGE = "photos/users/";

}
```

Comment: Well, post the source code of the class FilePaths, because it is not the official class from Android framework.

Comment: I did it just now:)

Comment: The code you are using does not work because the way you are using `FilePaths` is not consistent with your class. Take a look at my answer will help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason is simple. It's because you haven't defined the variable `DOWNLOAD` in the `FilePaths.class`. You also shouldn't point to the path like this, instead of that, use one or more of this variables:

```
Environment.getDataDirectory()
Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory()
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
Environment.getRootDirectory()
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_ALARMS)
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS)
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PODCASTS)
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES)
```

So your FilePaths should looks like this:

```
public class FilePaths {

    //"storage/emulated/0"
    public String ROOT_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

    public String DOWNLOADS = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    public String PICTURES = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    public String CAMERA = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

    public String ALARMS = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_ALARMS);
    public String DOCUMENTS = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
    public String MOVIES = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
    public String MUSIC = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
    public String NOTIFICATIONS = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS);
    public String PODCASTS = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PODCASTS);
    public String RINGTONES = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES);

    public String FIREBASE_IMAGE_STORAGE = "photos/users/";

}
```

Comment: But where exactly should I put these variables? In which class etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is in general not a good idea to use class names for your own class that are similar to java classes! Calling your class `FilePaths` will lead to confusion.

Change the name of your class to `MyFilePaths` (or something else!).

Then you can make the java file "MyFilePaths.java". Make the class `public` and make your variables `static final`:

```
public class MyFilePaths {

//"storage/emulated/0"
public static final String ROOT_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

public static final String PICTURES = ROOT_DIR + "/Pictures";
public static final String CAMERA = ROOT_DIR + "/DCIM/camera";

public static final String FIREBASE_IMAGE_STORAGE = "photos/users/";

}
```

Now you can do this:

```
directories.add(MyFilePaths.CAMERA);
```

**Edit**

In your code you call:

```
FilePaths filePaths = new FilePaths();
```

But your `FilePaths` class does not have a public constructor.

Comment: @PozeraczSloikow :: Have had the chance to look at my explanation?